# HTML,CSS Float:left image wrapping

Tags: css, html

Hi for some reason my images are staggering on my page I want them all too the left vertically they are all floated to the left but seem to overlap the previous article do i need to add clear: both; somewhere? Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/j56d51rb/

```css
body {
background-image: url(vespablue.jpg);
}

#wrapper {
overflow: hidden;
width: 960px;
margin: 1% auto;
height: auto;
background-color: white;
border: 2px solid black;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 1px black;
}

/*start of navigation*/
#navigation {
border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
width: 960px;
}

#navigation ul {
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
overflow:hidden;
}

#navigation ul li {
float: left;  
border-right: 1px solid #333;
list-style-type: none;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#navigation ul li a {
display: block; 
padding: 0.4em 1.5em;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#navigation a:link {
color: #333;
text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation a:visited {
color: #006600;
text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation a:hover {
color: #ff0000;
text-decoration: none;
}
/*end of navigation*/

/*Start of breadcrumbs*/
#breadcrumbs {
display: inline;
margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}


/*End of breadcrumbs*/

#main {
width: 960px;
height: auto;
float:left;
}

#mainleft {
width: 660px;
float:left;
padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

#mainleft h2 {
margin: 1em 1em 0.2em 0.8em;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#rightcol {
float: left;
width: 220px;
padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

#rightcol h3 {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
}

#mainleft h4 {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#main h2 {
margin: 1em 1em 0.2em 0.8em;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

h3 {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
margin: 1em 1em 0.2em 0.8em;
}

p {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
margin: 0 1em 1em 1.3em;
}

hr {
width: 850px;
background: #333;
}

article {

width: auto;
height: auto;
margin: 0em 1em 2.5em 1em;
padding: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
}

article h3 {
margin: 1em 1em 1em 0.8em;
}

div.homeimage {
float: left;
margin: 0 0.5em 1em 1em;
}

div.productsimage {
float: left;
margin: 0 0.5em 1em 1em;
}

article p {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}

img {
display: block;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
}

/*start of link style*/
a:link {
color: #0000ff;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
color: #006600;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
color: #ff0000;
text-decoration: underline;
}
/*end of link style*/

footer {
clear: both;
margin-bottom: 0.2em;
text-align: center;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header id="banner">
            <img src="banner.png" alt="Modern World" width="960" height="150">
        </header>
        <nav id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="#">History</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="products.html">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navigatiom"><a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="mainleft">
            <h3>Parka Coats</h3>
            <article>
                <div class="productsimage">
                    <img src="m51parka.jpg" alt="M-51 Parka Coat" width="150" height="200">
                </div>
                <h4>M-1951 Fishtail Parka</h4>
                <p>Authentic U.S. Military Issue M-1951 Fishtail Parka's were the original parka coats worn by Mods in the 1960s. The mohair frieze / nylon liner is much heavier than its successor, the M-1965 fishtail parka and produced using finer materials. M-1951's are becoming increasingly rare and hard to find. We only sell M-1951's which pass our inspection tests.</p>
                <br>
                <p>REF 761/1367</p>
            </article>
            <article>
                <div class="productsimage">
                    <img src="m65parka.jpg" alt="M-65 Parka Coat" width="150" height="204">
                </div>
                <h4>M-1965 Fishtail Parka</h4>
                <p>The M-1965 is an excellent alternative to the M-1951 fishtail parka, its both warmer and lighter than the M-1951 and will last you for years and at a much lower price.</p>
                <br>
                <p>REF 761/1368</p>
            </article>
            <h3>Jackets</h3>
            <article>
                <div class="productsimage">
                    <img src="harrington.jpg" alt="Harrington Jacket" width="150" height="204">
                </div>
                <h4>Harrington Jacket</h4>
                <P>Carefully crafted in the original style our Harringtons are 100% quality, available in all sizes and currently only available in Navy Blue but with more colours to come very soon.</P>
                <br>
                <p>REF 762/2743</p>
            </article>
            <h3>Suits</h3>
            <article>
                <div class="productsimage">
                    <img src="charcoalsuit.jpg" alt="Charcoal Check Suit" width="150" height="225">
                </div>
                <h4>Check Mod Slim-Fit Suit - Charcoal</h4>
                <p>A beautiful Italin mod suit available in charcoal check with a three button Jacket with double side vents and flat fronted trousers.</p>
                <br>
                <p>REF 765/2821</p>
            </article>
            <article>
                <div class="productsimage">
                    <img src="graysuit.jpg" alt="Gray Check Suit" width="150" height="225">
                </div>
                <h4>Check Mod Slim-Fit Suit - Gray</h4>
                <p>A beautiful Italin mod suit available in gray check with a three button Jacket with double side vents and flat fronted trousers.</p>
                <br>
                <p>REF 765/2822</p>
            </article>
            <h3>Shirts</h3>
            <article>
                <div class="productsimage">
                    <img src="shirtbr.jpg" alt="Check Shirt Blue/Red" width="150" height="177">
                </div>
                <h4>Mod Check Shirt - Blue/Red</h4>
                <p>A classic mod short sleeve shirt with blue and red checks and all the bells and whistles to give that 60s mod style to your wardrobe</p>
                <br>
                <p>REF 767/3489</p>
            </article>
            <article>
                <div class="productsimage">
                    <img src="shirtwb.jpg" alt="Check Shirt White/Blue" width="150" height="177">
                </div>
                <h4>Mod Check Shirt - White/Blue</h4>
                <p>A classic mod short sleeve shirt with white and blue checks and all the bells and whistles to give that 60s mod style to your wardrobe</p>
                <br>
                <p>REF 767/3490</p>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div id="rightcol">
            <aside>
                <h3>Purchase Information</h3>
                <p>Looking on making a purchase no problem?
                    <br>With each item there will be a seven digit reference code when calling quote the reference code and the quantity for your order to be proessed.</p>
                <h3>Contact Details</h3>
                <p>You can contact us by calling us on 01782 321980 or send a email with your details to our <a href="mailto:sales@modern-world.com">sales department</a>.</p>

            </aside>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <small>&copy; 2015 <a href="mailto:admin@modern-world.com">Gareth Bailey</a> All Rights Reserved</small>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please do not try to get around the warning that prevents you from only posting a link to jsfiddle. You need to put the minimal relevant code *in the question itself*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the article-tags expand to contain all floated children.

```
article { overflow: hidden; }
```

```css
body {
background-image: url(vespablue.jpg);
}

#wrapper {
overflow: hidden;
width: 960px;
margin: 1% auto;
height: auto;
background-color: white;
border: 2px solid black;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 1px black;
}

/*start of navigation*/
#navigation {
border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
width: 960px;
}

#navigation ul {
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
overflow:hidden;
}

#navigation ul li {
float: left;  
border-right: 1px solid #333;
list-style-type: none;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#navigation ul li a {
display: block; 
padding: 0.4em 1.5em;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#navigation a:link {
color: #333;
text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation a:visited {
color: #006600;
text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation a:hover {
color: #ff0000;
text-decoration: none;
}
/*end of navigation*/

/*Start of breadcrumbs*/
#breadcrumbs {
display: inline;
margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}


/*End of breadcrumbs*/

#main {
width: 960px;
height: auto;
float:left;
}

#mainleft {
width: 660px;
float:left;
padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

#mainleft h2 {
margin: 1em 1em 0.2em 0.8em;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#rightcol {
float: left;
width: 220px;
padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

#rightcol h3 {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
}

#mainleft h4 {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#main h2 {
margin: 1em 1em 0.2em 0.8em;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

h3 {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
margin: 1em 1em 0.2em 0.8em;
}

p {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
margin: 0 1em 1em 1.3em;
}

hr {
width: 850px;
background: #333;
}

article {

width: auto;
height: auto;
margin: 0em 1em 2.5em 1em;
padding: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
overflow: hidden;
}

article h3 {
margin: 1em 1em 1em 0.8em;
}

div.homeimage {
float: left;
margin: 0 0.5em 1em 1em;
}

div.productsimage {
float: left;
margin: 0 0.5em 1em 1em;
}

article p {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}

img {
display: block;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
}

/*start of link style*/
a:link {
color: #0000ff;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
color: #006600;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
color: #ff0000;
text-decoration: underline;
}
/*end of link style*/

footer {
clear: both;
margin-bottom: 0.2em;
text-align: center;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header id="banner">
            <img src="banner.png" alt="Modern World" width="960" height="150">
        </header>
        <nav id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="#">History</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="products.html">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navigation"><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navigatiom"><a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="mainleft">
            <h3>Parka Coats</h3>
            <article>
                <div class="productsimage">
                    <img src="m51parka.jpg" alt="M-51 Parka Coat" width="150" height="200">
                </div>
                <h4>M-1951 Fishtail Parka</h4>
                <p>Authentic U.S. Military Issue M-1951 Fishtail Parka's were the original parka coats worn by Mods in the 1960s. The mohair frieze / nylon liner is much heavier than its successor, the M-1965 fishtail parka and produced using finer materials. M-1951's are becoming increasingly rare and hard to find. We only sell M-1951's which pass our inspection tests.</p>
                <br>
                <p>REF 761/1367</p>
            </article>
            <article>
                <div class="productsimage">
                    <img src="m65parka.jpg" alt="M-65 Parka Coat" width="150" height="204">
                </div>
                <h4>M-1965 Fishtail Parka</h4>
                <p>The M-1965 is an excellent alternative to the M-1951 fishtail parka, its both warmer and lighter than the M-1951 and will last you for years and at a much lower price.</p>
                <br>
                <p>REF 761/1368</p>
            </article>
            <h3>Jackets</h3>
            <article>
                <div class="productsimage">
                    <img src="harrington.jpg" alt="Harrington Jacket" width="150" height="204">
                </div>
                <h4>Harrington Jacket</h4>
                <P>Carefully crafted in the original style our Harringtons are 100% quality, available in all sizes and currently only available in Navy Blue but with more colours to come very soon.</P>
                <br>
                <p>REF 762/2743</p>
            </article>
            <h3>Suits</h3>
            <article>
                <div class="productsimage">
                    <img src="charcoalsuit.jpg" alt="Charcoal Check Suit" width="150" height="225">
                </div>
                <h4>Check Mod Slim-Fit Suit - Charcoal</h4>
                <p>A beautiful Italin mod suit available in charcoal check with a three button Jacket with double side vents and flat fronted trousers.</p>
                <br>
                <p>REF 765/2821</p>
            </article>
            <article>
                <div class="productsimage">
                    <img src="graysuit.jpg" alt="Gray Check Suit" width="150" height="225">
                </div>
                <h4>Check Mod Slim-Fit Suit - Gray</h4>
                <p>A beautiful Italin mod suit available in gray check with a three button Jacket with double side vents and flat fronted trousers.</p>
                <br>
                <p>REF 765/2822</p>
            </article>
            <h3>Shirts</h3>
            <article>
                <div class="productsimage">
                    <img src="shirtbr.jpg" alt="Check Shirt Blue/Red" width="150" height="177">
                </div>
                <h4>Mod Check Shirt - Blue/Red</h4>
                <p>A classic mod short sleeve shirt with blue and red checks and all the bells and whistles to give that 60s mod style to your wardrobe</p>
                <br>
                <p>REF 767/3489</p>
            </article>
            <article>
                <div class="productsimage">
                    <img src="shirtwb.jpg" alt="Check Shirt White/Blue" width="150" height="177">
                </div>
                <h4>Mod Check Shirt - White/Blue</h4>
                <p>A classic mod short sleeve shirt with white and blue checks and all the bells and whistles to give that 60s mod style to your wardrobe</p>
                <br>
                <p>REF 767/3490</p>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div id="rightcol">
            <aside>
                <h3>Purchase Information</h3>
                <p>Looking on making a purchase no problem?
                    <br>With each item there will be a seven digit reference code when calling quote the reference code and the quantity for your order to be proessed.</p>
                <h3>Contact Details</h3>
                <p>You can contact us by calling us on 01782 321980 or send a email with your details to our <a href="mailto:sales@modern-world.com">sales department</a>.</p>

            </aside>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <small>&copy; 2015 <a href="mailto:admin@modern-world.com">Gareth Bailey</a> All Rights Reserved</small>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Another solution is to use a clearfix. Read more here:
http://www.impressivewebs.com/clearing-floats-why-necessary/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @DavidAnsermot Yes it does, but It might not have been clear, sorry. I've now made a suggested edit the question which copies the code from jsfiddle to a SO code snippet. I then copied and applied the fix into my answer, so soon both will have runnable code, I hope. Or was it something else you were thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do the following on each article.

```
article {
    clear: both;
}
```